# Python required positional argument when use "self"

Tags: python, arguments, self

I read that the first parameter of methods is the instance the method is called on. 
I dont understand why when i write this

```
class A:
    def printName(self, name):
        print(name)

A.printName("asd")
```

I get that error TypeError: printName() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'.
What i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a class instance and then call method on that instance:

```
class A:
    def printName(self, name):
        print(name)

class_instance = A()
class_instance.printName("asd")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
I dont really get that A.printName("asd") is not an instance

Comment: A is a class object while A() is a new class instance:

Comment: Take a look to documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

It's pretty important to know basis about classes. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This would work, using `staticmethod` if you want to call `printName()` without creating an instance of that class

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def printName(name):
        print(name)

A.printName('hello')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Can you explain what is a static method in python and why it dont need the 'self'?,
I tried your code and it works even without the @staticmethod, why is that?
Sorry for the amount of questions but i'm having a lot of trouble to understant how works the 'self' argument

Comment: @akerbeltz:) **staticmethods** are methods that are bound to a class rather than its object. They don't need class instance`@staticmethod` tells we are using `staticmethod`. In earlier versions, the syntax to write **staticmethod** was different. You can just google for more information

Comment: self is an equivalent of, for 'this' object. staticmethod is not for different instances it is bound to a class.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! you help me a lot.
There's something i don't understand at all. When i write `A.printName('hello')` or `a=A.printName('hello')` i'm not creating an instance of the class A?

Comment: @akerbeltz :) No, you are not creating instance in either way. You can create an instance like `instance_A = A()`. if the answer was helpful, please mark the answer as _accept_ answer.